# Character encoding SQL ASCII to UTF-8 corruption

Tags: node.js, postgresql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am working with a Postgres database which is encoded in `SQL ASCII`.

With node.js, using [pg package](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), I am requesting some rows, which may contains accents.

When I display raw data from request inside my browser, I got thoses corrupted characters :
[image]

I have tried to send data with some UTF-8 encoding, but there is the same issue :
[image]

Here the code :

```
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>1 all�e Carl Faberg�</body></html>
```

The Developer Tools too, don't display this character :
[image]

Using pgAdmin software, to explore database, I don't have any problem :
[image]

To me, it seems the issue is coming from Node.js, but I don't know what solutions I have.

Do you have an idea how can I resolve this ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have used SQL_ASCII database encoding because that way PostgreSQL doesn't care about encoding and doesn't convert strings to the proper client encoding either.

With SQL_ASCII, the burden to convert the characters to the correct encoding (probably UTF-16 since you are using Javascript) rests on the application, so you will have to write the conversion yourself, perhaps using a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

First you'll have to find out in what encoding the characters in the database are actually stored. You can find out the bytes stored in the database by casting the string to `bytea` like this:

```
test=> SELECT 'allée Carl Fabergé'::bytea;
┌────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                   bytea                    │
├────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ \x616c6cc3a965204361726c20466162657267c3a9 │
└────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```